# Selecting a json key-value pair dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json like this one:

```
{
    "index": 1,
    "ln": "27953",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "availability": {
        "day0726": "G",
        "day0727": "G",
        "day0728": "G",
    }
}
```

And I'd like to display the availability dynamically based on what date is it. "day0726" is July 26 for example. How could I display the value of the correct day using the following code piece:

```
import React from "react"
import Product from "./Product"

const Productlist = ({ prodlist }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                prodlist.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Product
                            key={prodlist[i].index}
                            name={prodlist[i].name}
                            ln={prodlist[i].ln}
                            availability={*this is I want to change dynamically*}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Productlist
```

Can it be done or is train of thought completely wrong?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** I can change the date key format to anything if that's necessary.

Comment: date API has different format. You may have to keys in your availability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to create a Date of the format you have and then you can use that in the component to get the products `availability` at a certain key:

```js
let date = new Date();
function str_pad(n) {
    return String("00" + n).slice(-2);
}
date = "day"+(str_pad(date.getMonth()+1))+str_pad(date.getDate());

console.log(date)
```

```
import React from "react"
import Product from "./Product"

let date = new Date();
function str_pad(n) {
  return String("00" + n).slice(-2);
}
date = "day"+(str_pad(date.getMonth()+1))+str_pad(date.getDate());


const Productlist = ({ prodlist }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                prodlist.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Product
                            key={prodlist[i].index}
                            name={prodlist[i].name}
                            ln={prodlist[i].ln}
                            availability={prodlist[i].availability[date]}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Productlist
```